# "Non existent tunnel" error then running browserstack-runner

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, browserstack

I'm trying to run browserstack-runner on my project, but I'm getting the following error (when running with --verbose):

```
Using config: /Users/xxx/browserstack.json
Launching server on port: 8888
Non existent tunnel
Exiting
```

I tried to replicate the configuration found on browserstack-runner-sample repo(https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-runner-sample), just to test.

I don't know what to do to fix this. Hope someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

There was another process using port 8888 already. In my case, it was MAMP(apache web server).
Killing the process using port 8888 solved problem.